# my mobile data is not working after i reseted my sumsung galaxy note 3

Tags: factory-reset, mobile-data

I wanted to format and reset my Samsung galaxy note 3 and I did a factory reset but after that my phone is having a hard time to identify the network provider(took a very long time to sign into the network automatically) and the mobile data is not working. I tried making it on airplane mode and then restarting it multiple times but it is still the same. please let me know if you have any suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually after booting up the first time you should get a configuration SMS from your provider. This SMS can be delayed, just wait for about an hour leaving the phone connected to the mobile network. Or check the web page of your mobile network provider on the APN settings you have to configure. Then you could do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Reset network setting again. Manually enter APN setting. For that
Go to setting / connection  / mobile network / Access point name. Manually enter apn details.

Turn off data saver. Go to setting / connection / data usage / data saver.
Make sure you have good network signal. Other wise reinsert sim.

Update mobile software.

Make sure data roaming is off. setting /connections  mobile network / data roaming.

Temporary remove from network and again reconnect to network.